# Get a list of common friends between more than 2 users in graph database

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am working with Titan graph database (v1.0), and I am looking for gremlin query to find the mutual friends between more than 2 users. Suppose I have a "user1", "user2", and "user3". I want to find the mutual friends between these 3 users. I know that the following query will give me the mutual friends between "user1" and "user2", but how can I find the mutual friends between more than 2 users? I know for two users I can use the following query:

```
g.V(user1).both("friend").where(both("friend").is(eq(user2)))
```

What about more than 2 users? I know I can do the same with all pairs, but this is not an efficient query!

Answer (score 3):

The `match()` step will probably be your best choice as it's the easiest to read and write. Might not be the fastest though.

```
g.V().has("name","user1").as("u1").
  V().has("name","user2").as("u2").
  V().has("name","user3").as("u3").
  match(
    __.as("u1").both("friend").as("f"),
    __.as("u2").both("friend").as("f"),
    __.as("u3").both("friend").as("f")
  ).where("f", neq("u1").and(neq("u2")).and(neq("u3"))).select("f")
```

Here's the query in action: http://www.gremlinbin.com/bin/view/570a30f9a58c9

Alternatively (without mid-traversal `V()`'s and without the `where()` conditions) you could do:

```
g.V().has("name","user1").both("friend").and(
    both("friend").has("name","user2"),
    both("friend").has("name","user3"))
```

Comment: Does the part ".where("f", neq("u1").and(neq("u2")).and(neq("u3")))" is necessary? One can not be a friend of herself in my data model.

Comment: `user1` can be friend with `user2`. If you want to allow any of the input users to appear in the result, then you don't need the `where()`.

Comment: Dear Daniel, If "user1" has a friendship relation with "user1", one should exclude the "user1" from the result, but if there is no self-relationship in data model, there is no need to exclude "user1" from result, since there will be not any "user1" in the result.

Comment: I was never talking about self-looping edges (that wouldn't make much sense). I'm talking about friendships between 2 or more different users that are all part of the input user set.

Comment: It seems that the provided query does not supported in Titan 1.0 which is based on tinkerpop 3.0.1 incubating. Do you know any alternative query?

Comment: @DanielKuppitz Is there a way to achieve this in java? ("g.V().has("name","user1").as("u1")" returns a GraphTraversal which can't be continued by a second "V()")

Comment: Can you upgrade to Titan 1.1 (build it from source)? I think we've added mid-traversal `V()`'s in TinkerPop 3.1.x.

Comment: I am afraid I cant. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Added an alternative way w/o mid-traversal `V()`'s, `match()` and `where()`.